# How to push string on JsonArrayRequest

Tags: android

I want to get data from sql on listview, but only get the data that i created.
But the server does not receive the value

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_READ, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
        {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("userid", getId);
            return params;
        }
};
```

Comment: Check this link : https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

Comment: The first thing I noticed is you are using a value "URL_READ"  (on a "POST" request), which I would assume is a script on your server that is for "read-only" operations! Perhaps you just need to use the right script OR be more vigilant on naming your constant values.

Comment: that's a name..